# Menu in my Android app not working

Tags: android, menu

I followed the following link to create a test application to create menu:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

It worked for me. However, when I added it to my app which is a google map app, menu is not working. I suspect its because the in the sample I created I extended Activity class but in my app I have extended MapActivity class. 
Can someone explain how can i do it?

Comment: What is your code look like?

How do you know it's not working? One of my students did not push the menu button, just waited for the menu to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Menu is working same for MapActivity as for Activity class. You just need to override onCreateOptionsMenu method. Doublecheck your resource name R.menu.mapmenu etc.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mapmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```